# Proofs that relied on paradoxical sentences

Tags: logic, math-history, paradoxes

Graham Priest's *Logic of Paradox* is a modification of classical logic where the principle of explosion does not hold, so that there are inconsistent theories which are not automatically trivial. Priest writes that in general, we may use classical logic as long as no paradoxial sentences are involved. But sometimes it might turn out that a part of the proof was based on a paradox so that it turns out to be invalid (because the proof used rules of inference that apply only to non-paradoxical sentences, sentences that are either only true or only false but not both).

What are interesting examples in the history of mathematics where a proof relied on a paradoxical proposition? Could it be in principle any proof that turned out false?

"However, it is always possiile
that semantic terms may be smuggled implicitly into a sentence without
our knowledge or that paradoxicality arises for some other reason of which
we are not aware. We may then invoke the maxim but find that at a later
time evidence turns up to the effect that there are paradoxical sentences in
the proof and that they occur in such a way as to invalidate a quasi-valid
rule of inference. We will then have to reject the proof that we previously
accepted. Although this may sound a little unrealistic, there is in fact
nothing essentially new in this situation to those who are familiar with a
little of the **history of mathematics**." http://philpapers.org/rec/PRITLO